# I want to fetch rows in a first table that are not in a second table

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table, let's call it `fees`, and two other tables, let's call them `transactions` and `breakdowns`.

`transactions` table saves the general summary of payments received while `breakdowns` table saves the breakdown of the payments.

breakdowns table looks something like this

```
id | transaction_id | fee_id
```

and fees table looks something like this

```
id | amount | description
```

I'd like to fetch the fees in fees table that do not have records in breakdowns table based on the transaction_id

```
SELECT * FROM fees LEFT JOIN breakdowns ON (fees.id = breakdowns.fee_id) 
WHERE breakdowns.transaction_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

The code above returns empty rows

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM fees f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM breakdowns b
                  WHERE b.fee_id = f.id AND
                        b.transaction_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
                 );
```

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` as well, moving the condition on `breakdowns` to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM fees f LEFT JOIN
     breakdowns b
     ON b.fee_id = f.id AND  
        b.transaction_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

However, I think `NOT EXISTS` more directly captures the logic you want.  Also, I see no reason to return the `NULL` values for the columns in `breakdowns`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data['showrecord'] = DB::table('fees')
           ->where('breakdown.transaction_id',"=",'xxxxx')
           ->leftjoin('breakdown', 'breakdown.fee_id', '=', 'fees.id')
           ->get();
```